# Unexpected array values from MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I know this is basic, but I can't seem to find the answer:

I have a query that returns the desired rows in PHPMyAdmin but am clearly doing something wrong on my page because it only seems two return rows in the array.

Here is the code:

```
$editgroupid =  'm101';

$query = "SELECT dentists.id
    from groups, groupdentlink, dentists
    WHERE groups.id = '$editgroupid'
    AND groups.id = groupdentlink.f_group_id
    AND groupdentlink.f_dent_id = dentists.id
    ORDER BY dentists.name";

    $resultdent = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $dents = mysql_fetch_array($resultdent);
    print_r(array_values($dents));
```

On the page I get:

Array ( [0] => UTG69 [1] => UTG69 )

But in PHPMyAdmin I get like 40 rows.

Comment: not all of your code was in a code block, i fixed that

Comment: Are you running the output of `$query` in PHPMyAdmin or typing what you *think* the query is?

Answer (score 3):

[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) only returns one row at a time. To get all the rows, generally you loop through, calling mysql_fetch_array each time.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultdent)) {
    // Here you have access to the current $row
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Currently Googling 'put mysql result into array'.

Answer (score 0):

You are usingmysql_fetch_array() function which as you can see in documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) loads only one row retrieved from query. At given site you have example how to manage multiple rows.